# Arraylist to print objects with count

Tags: java

This is my code

```
ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurant= new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
```

Inside Restaurant class,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    int i=1;
    return "\n"+(i++)+". "+this.restaurantName + 
           "\t\t"+this.location;
}
```

I want to print like this

> [ 1. pizzahut      bangalore, 2. dominos       delhi]

instead it prints

> [ 1. pizzahut      bangalore, 1. dominos       delhi]

Help in code needed.

Comment: use static int i =1 as class variable, also initialize the static variable i =1 before iterating the list

Comment: @RakeshSoni that ain't going to work.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  But is it a real problem you are trying to solve, or is it a question (with intentional restrictions) from school that is designed to make you think?  Please state the answer to this in your question because it effect how it should be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution,  I am not sure what actual problem you have, so just provide another possible solution. this might work for you.

```
public class Restaurant {

    static int index = 1;
    String restaurantName;
    String location;
    int curIndex;

    Restaurant(final String restaurantName, final String location) {
        this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
        this.location = location;
        this.curIndex = index++;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] input) {
        final ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurant = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
        restaurant.add(new Restaurant("pizzahut", "bangalore"));
        restaurant.add(new Restaurant("dominos", "delhi"));

        restaurant.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + curIndex + ". " + this.restaurantName +
                "\t\t" + this.location;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem that printing an index that has no correlation to the item's index in the `List` is somewhat ... unusual. Whilst the ctor assignment avoids the degenerate behaviour of another (now deleted) answer, this is still a Bad Idea TM.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurantList= new ArrayList<Restaurant>(); 

// your login to insert the elements in the array list 

// iterate list
int index=1;
for(Restaurant r : restaurantList){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(index++)+": "+ r);
}
```

Inside Restaurant class,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.restaurantName + "\t\t"+this.location;
}
```